# Deploy Blazor web application on file share

Tags: blazor

Blazor can be used to create a client-side-C#-scripted webpage. I have read in various places (like [MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt829752)) that once built I can put the files on any server. My understanding is that placing the artifacts on a file share should be possible, too.

Yet, this is not what I observe. Running `dotnet run` in the project directory of the Blazor Web Application I created via the template in Visual Studio makes the kestrel webserver spin up and I can reach the working web page via the indicated `http://localhost:port/` address.

When I open the `index.html` which was generated under the `WebApplication1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\publish\WebApplication1\dist` path with the help of `dotnet publish` I only see a text saying "Loading..." in my web browser.

I have looked into the `index.html` and at first sight it looks like the path to the `_framework/blazor.webassembly.js` matches the directory structure. Where is the catch?

Comment: once you use `dotnet publish` and only see "Loading..." check your js console. You will find some errors because of some missing files. You will need to relocate these files. This is how I fixed this a while back and don't remember the exact fix

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> When I open the index.html which was generated under the WebApplication1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\publish\WebApplication1\dist path with the help of dotnet publish I only see a text saying "Loading..." in my web browser.

This is because Blazor expect to locate dll's on root path. I mean, all will work fine if you copy the content of `dist` on the root of your web server but not if you copy it on a "subfolder" of root.

If you want to serve files from a path (instead from root), then you should to set [app base path](https://blazor.net/docs/host-and-deploy/index.html#app-base-path) I mean, change:

```
<base href="/" />
```

to

```
<base href="/your_path/" />
```

on `index.html` page.

From docs:

> The app base path is the virtual app root path on the server. For example, an app that resides on the Contoso server in a virtual folder at `/CoolBlazorApp/` is reached at `https://www.contoso.com/CoolBlazorApp` and has a virtual base path of `/CoolBlazorApp/`.

Comment: Does this mean Blazor Client-Side app can run from folder too (without any webs server).. please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @DeepakShaw. If your app doesn't run at root of url path you need to set `base`. For example, [BlazorConfirm](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/BlazorConfirm) runs on `https://ctrl-alt-d.github.io/BlazorConfirm/` instead of `https://ctrl-alt-d.github.io/`. This is an answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

I started an HTTP server with a port number on a folder and the application worked fine with URL like http://localhost:4565/. Used [this HTTP server code](https://gist.github.com/aksakalli/9191056). But in general, any HTTP server works just fine.